# Extension of function with values in a Banach space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

I want to prove the following

> Let $E,X$ be Banach spaces, and $Y\subset E$ a closed subspace with codimension $1$. Let $T:Y \to X$ be a continuous linear function. Then there exists a continuous linear extension  $\bar{T}$ of $T$ defined on $E$

my attempt: Let's say that $E=Y \oplus \mathbb{R}e$, for some $e \in E\setminus{Y}$. Define for $r \in \mathbb{R} $  and $y \in Y$
$$
\bar{T}(y+re):=T(y)
$$
so I tried to prove that 
$$
\sup_{x \in B_E} \|\bar{T}(x)\|=\sup_{\|y+re\|\leq 1} \|T(y)\|< \infty
$$
I'd like to say something like this: There exists $M>0$ such that
$$
\|y+re\|\leq 1\, \text{for some $r\in \mathbb{R}$}\Longrightarrow \|y\|\leq M
$$
which, I suppose, comes from the fact that $Y$ is closed. If I had that, I could say the following
$$
\sup_{\|y+re\|\leq 1} \|T(y)\|\leq \sup_{\|y\|\leq M}\|T(y)\|
$$
and conclude the proof. Any hint would be welcome.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Hint: consider $d := \operatorname{dist}(e,Y) = \inf \{ \lVert e-y\rVert : y \in Y\}$.

Comment: The line that you are trying to prove (i.e. $\|y+re\|\le 1\Rightarrow \|y\|\le M$) amounts to the proof that the projection of $E$ onto $Y$ along the vector $e$ is a continuous linear operator.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I can show that $\exists M>0$ such that $\|y+Me\|> 1$ for all $y \in Y$, then $\|y\|\leq 1+M\|e\|$ for $y$ with $\|y+re\|\leq 1$.